# How to separate data based on null values in two different CSV files in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-processing, export-to-text

I am new to python development and and I am trying to separate csv file into two different text files based on null values

my csv file has data like

[image]

and

[image]

My csv file contains four fields facility, Truck, Driver and licences
truck and driver has some of the null values
I want to create two separate files for row values where truck value us null and another file will contain information where driver value is null.

I tried the following code but it is not eliminating null values it shows either 0 or space in text file

```
    License = pd.read_csv("E:\ActiveCityLicenses.csv")

    a=License.isnull().sum()
    print(a)
    print(License.shape)
    m=License[License['TRUCK_ID'].isnull()]
    print(m)
    n=License.dropna(axis= 0, subset= ['TRUCK_ID'], inplace=True)
    print(n)

    License.to_csv(r'E:\DriverLicense.txt', header=None, index=None, mode='w', columns=None)
    #I had to create two data frames as after doing first dorpna entire frame gets empty


    License1 = pd.read_csv("E:\ActiveCityLicenses.csv")
    p=License1.dropna(axis= 0, subset= ['EMPLOYEE_ID'], inplace=True)
    print(p)

    License1.to_csv(r'E:\TruckLicense.txt', header=None, index=None, sep=',', mode='w')
```

Can anyone please suggest a better approach of doing it, or what I am missing over here?
output in the text file is

```
     A119,BF01,,TOR|MARK|BRAM|MISS|RHILL|VAU
     A119,BF03,,TOR|MARK|BRAM|MISS|RHILL|VAU
     A119,BF04,,TOR|MARK|BRAM|MISS|RHILL|VAU
     A119,BF05,,TOR|MARK|BRAM|MISS|RHILL|VAU
```

space should not be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df= df[pd.notnull(df['TRUCK_ID'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure the empty column is not there, you can always remove the column by doing for example: 
`License.drop(labels="EMPLOYEE_ID", axis=1, inplace=True)`
I am not entirely sure where you want which column removed, so I cannot give a more complete solution.